# Extracting 3 values using json extractor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

i am new to performance testing, currently working on one scenario where we need to correlate id, field type & allowed_otypes(first value of the payload)

all of the these three variables are interlinked to each other, i need to pick id, field type & allowed_otypes in one json expression, if i do individually then then script is getting failed due to miss match in the passing of wrong values

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "field_type": "DISPLAY_SET",
        "tooltip_text": null,
        "name_plural": "Approvers",
        "name_singular": "Approver",
        "backref_name": null,
        "backref_tooltip_text": null,
        "allow_multiple": true,
        "allowed_otypes": [
            "user",
            "groupprofile",
            "groupprofile"
        ],
        "options": null,
        "builtin_name": "approver",
        "can_view": null,
        "can_edit": null,
        "flavor": "DEFAULT",
        "tag_ds_id": null,
        "tag_schema_name": null
    },
    {
        "id": 10022,
        "field_type": "DATA_SET",
        "tooltip_text": "Approvers",
        "name_plural": "Approvers",
        "name_singular": "Approvers",
        "backref_name": "Approvers",
        "backref_tooltip_text": "Approvers",
        "allow_multiple": true,
        "allowed_otypes": [
            "profile",
            "groupprofile",
            "groupprofile"
        ],
        "options": null,
        "builtin_name": null,
        "can_view": null,
        "can_edit": null,
        "flavor": "DEFAULT",
        "tag_ds_id": null,
        "tag_schema_name": null
    }
]
```

need to pass correlated values in the next sampler individually, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to extract a single set of variables for example for first item in the [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) you can do this using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configured like:

- Names of created variables: `id;field_type;allowed_otypes`
- JSON Path Expressions: `[0].id;[0].field_type;[0].allowed_otypes[0]`

in this case you will have the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) created:

```
allowed_otypes=user
field_type=DISPLAY_SET
id=12
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)